# Convertion from unix time to Calendar - there is a one hour inconsistency

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, unix-timestamp, datetime-conversion

I have written this method to convert unix time to a calendar object:

```
     /**
 * Converts Unix time to Calendar instance.
 */
public static Calendar unixToCalendar(long unixTime){
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1970/*Year*/, GregorianCalendar.JANUARY/*0*/,       1 /*Day*/, 00, 0);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) (unixTime/60/* Sec to Min */));
    return calendar;
}
```

the problem is that for bigger input values i get an exactly one hour diffrence bettween the real time to the result.

the difference starts somewhere between the 796000000 values...

For example until 796000000 we get the same results (matches reality), but for 797000000 and up we get a one hour difference (my code in one hour forward).

If i use :

calendar.setTimeInMillis(unixTime*1000);

i get the same problem just with 3-2 hours diffrence from reality (same values).

I used some online sites to check myself, and i'm looking for a result in GMT 0.
http://www.epochconverter.com/
http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Thank you

Comment: Where is the server located?  Do you do know what daylight savings time is?

Comment: hi, i read and i checked: System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone( my area).inDaylightTime(new Date())); and it returns false. Anyway i'm not sure it has anything to do with DST

Comment: So this is not just a 1 hour inconsistency?

Comment: it is just a 1 hour inconsistency (for values greater than ~797000000 ). why do you think it is not?

Comment: What if day is wrongly set on server and because of it error occurs?

Answer (score 6):

The recommended way to do it is to retrieve the local instance of Calendar:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Then use the setTimeInMillis() method to pass in the Unix time. Like this:

```
/**
 * Converts Unix time to Calendar instance.
 */
public static Calendar unixToCalendar(long unixTime){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(unixTime);
    return calendar;
}
```

Comment: Hi Liv, as i wrote i tried this way too but the same problem occurs. thanks